# Android: Access to ContentProvider from external service

Tags: android, android-service, external, android-contentprovider

We have an Android project where I use an external Service to handle all the networking stuff for different apps. Now a friend of mine had the task to implement a ContentProvider which is used in the main app and should be accessible from the external Service.

Now I tried to get access to these data: The external Service is in the project of the main app but gets null from getLocalContentProvider. Probably because it is started from an other process (due to the externality of the Service)... In the main app it's no problem to access the data...

Is there an other possibility to get the right ContentProvider?

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried accessing this `ContentProvider` using other means, like `query()` and such on `ContentResolver`? Few developers use `getLocalContentProvider()`, or anything on `ContentProviderClient`.

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsWare Thanks for your answer.
It works now directly with getContentResolver().query() instead of using the ContentProvider of getLocalContentProvider()